# How do I get the key where a property of the object is true?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using lodash and trying to figure out how to get the key name of the object that has the valid property set to true.

```
 this.booking = {
    personal:{ valid:false, data:{ } },
    listing:{ valid:true, data:{ } },
    cart:{ valid:false, data:{ } },
    checkout:{ valid:true, data:{ } }
  }

const result = _.map(this.booking, 'valid')
console.log(result) // returns [false, true, false, true]
```

How would I write a lodash function that would return `['listing', 'checkout]` based on the object above?

Comment: without lodash: `Object.keys(this.booking).filter(b => b.valid)`

Comment: @epascarello It should be an answer. An accepted answer :)

Comment: @Victor without the bug..... lol `b => this.booking[b].valid` lol.... I need more coffee

Answer (score 1):

Use [`_.pickBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pickBy) to filter the object, to valid properties, and then get the keys with [`_.keys()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#keys) (or [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)):

```js
const booking = {
  personal:{ valid:false, data:{ } },
  listing:{ valid:true, data:{ } },
  cart:{ valid:false, data:{ } },
  checkout:{ valid:true, data:{ } }
}

const result = _.keys(_.pickBy(booking, 'valid'));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Lodash for this:

```
Object.keys(this.booking)
  .filter((key) => this.booking[key].valid);

// returns ['listing', 'checkout']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, using `reduce` you can do it in a single iteration since `lodash#reduce` can be applied in object directly.

```
_.reduce(booking, (r, e, k) => (e.valid && r.push(k), r), [])
```

Working demo

```js
let bookings = {"personal":{"valid":false,"data":{}},"listing":{"valid":true,"data":{}},"cart":{"valid":false,"data":{}},"checkout":{"valid":true,"data":{}}},
    res = _.reduce(bookings, (r, e, k) => (e.valid && r.push(k), r), []);
    
    console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than few ways to do this for example here are few options with [`_.pickBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pickBy), [`_.omitBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#omitBy), and [`_.transform`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#transform):

```js
const obj = { personal:{ valid:false, data:{ } }, listing:{ valid:true, data:{ } }, cart:{ valid:false, data:{ } }, checkout:{ valid:true, data:{ } } }

console.log(_.keys(_.pickBy(obj, 'valid'))) 
console.log(_.keys(_.omitBy(obj, {valid: false})))
console.log(_.keys(_.transform(obj,(a, {valid}, k) => valid ? a[k] = valid : null)))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```